# Integral of integral — it takes too much time

Tags: numerical-integration

When I evaluate the following expression in *Mathematica*, it takes so much time that I don't want to wait for the evaluation to complete. So I think that there must be a better approach.

```
wewint[lx_?NumericQ, ly_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[
    Cos[lx]*Cos[qx] + Sin[lx]*Sin[qx], {qx, -Pi, Pi}, {qy, -Pi, Pi}, 
    Method -> Automatic];
NIntegrate[wewint[lx, ly], {lx, -Pi, Pi}, {ly, -Pi, Pi}, Method -> Automatic]
```

If I use `Cos[lx-qx]` instead of `(Cos[lx]*Cos[qx] + Sin[lx]*Sin[qx])`, the effect is the same. In reality, the expression I am working with is much more complicated and it couldn't be calculated analytically.

Comment: Should the integrand be `Cos[lx]*Cos[qx] + Sin[lx]*Sin[qx]` or `Cos[lx]*Cos[qx] + Sin[ly]*Sin[qy]`? If the former, than you are performing two unnecessary integrations. Also, as each point evaluated in the second integral requires a full evaluation of the first integral, it will take longer as there is a full init and tear down stage per evaluation. Can they be combined into one? This will eliminate the extra overhead.

Answer (score 10):

You may have some luck playing with various methods. It is also important to decrease the number of integrations - one 4-dimensional integral can often compute much faster than 2 two-dimensional ones (meaning 2d integral of 2d integrals). So, we have:

```
NIntegrate[Cos[lx]*Cos[qx]+Sin[lx]*Sin[qx],{qx,-Pi,Pi},{qy,-Pi,Pi},
  {lx,-Pi,Pi},{ly,-Pi,Pi},Method->"LocalAdaptive"]//AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.619141,0.}  *)
```

while for example

```
NIntegrate[Cos[lx]^2*Cos[qx]^2+Sin[lx]*Sin[qx],{qx,-Pi,Pi},{qy,-Pi,Pi},
   {lx,-Pi,Pi},{ly,-Pi,Pi},Method->"LocalAdaptive"]//AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.188476,389.636}  *)
```

and

```
{#,N[#]}&@Integrate[Cos[lx]^2*Cos[qx]^2+Sin[lx]*Sin[qx],{qx,-Pi,Pi},{qy,-Pi,Pi},
  {lx,-Pi,Pi},{ly,-Pi,Pi}]

(*  {4 \[Pi]^4,389.636}  *)
```

just to confirm.